# How to translate JS tests with Babel before running in R# test runner?

Tags: javascript, msbuild, resharper, babeljs

We want to write our JS specs in ES6 and translate them using Babel before running in the ReSharper test runner.  Currently, we're running the tests in Chrome (willing to use headless or PhantomJS if that turns out to be preferable) and executing Babel as an MSBuild task.  But we're not sure how to instruct R# to use our translated specs to build `Tests.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find a way into the `Tests.js` pipeline.  Doesn't seem possible.  So we're using npm-based test runner rather than the R# runner.